# Best practice to compress bitmap with LZ4

Tags: png, deflate, lz4

I'm packing some image resources for my game, and since this is a typical "compress once, decompress multiple" scenario, LZ4 High Compression fits me well (LZ4HC take longer time to compress, but decompress very fast).

I compressed a bitmap from 7.7MB to 3.0MB, which looks good to me, until I found that the PNG version is only 1.9MB.

I know that LZ4 HC do not have the ratio that deflate (which is used by PNG) does, but the ratio  2.55 vs 4.05 looks not right.

I searched and find that before compressing, PNG format will perform a **Filtering** operation, though I don't the details, it looks like that the Filtering move manipulate the data to fits the compress algorithm better.

So my question is:

1. Do I need to perform a filtering move before compressing using lz4?
2. If yes, where can I get a library (or code snippet) to perform filtering?
3. If no, is there any solution to make a PNG (or other lossless image formats) compress slow but decompress fast?

Comment: The filter details are [available](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG-Filters.html). That said, decompressing will take more time if you have to reverse the filtering as well. If you value decompression time over storage space, use what you have now. Else just use a PNG library and forget about optimizing decompression time.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know the filtering needs reverse back, that's a trade-off I need to consider.

Comment: Yes. The general idea is this: a sequence `0 1 2 3` can be reduced by a +1-filter to `0 0 0 0` and thus compress much better. However, *decompressing* yields that `0 0 0 0` again, so the +1-filter has to be applied to the decompressed result to get the original data back. It's one of the reasons PNG compresses better than your raw data.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest filtering in PNG is just taking the difference of subsequent pixels. The first pixel is sent as is, the next pixel is sent as the difference of that pixel and the previous pixel, and so on. That would be quite fast, and provide a good bit of the compression gain of filtering.

Comment: Do you mean that in my case, it is worth to do a filtering on a bitmap? I'll do the profile, I just asked.

Comment: Are you saying that it's one bit per pixel?

Comment: It's one byte per channel.

Comment: Good. Then just try differences to see how much gain you get.